# Python 3.x finding derivatives

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to make a derivative calculator.

Here is my code.

```
from sympy import symbols, Limit, S

x, h = symbols('x, h')

def g(x):
    def f(x):
        y = input("Function:")
        return eval(y, {'__builtins__': {}}, {'x': x})
    return Limit((f(x+h)-f(x))/h , h, S.Zero).doit()

print (g(x))
```

But when I run the code, I have to put the "Functions" twice. It seems that it happens because there are two f's ( f(x+h) and f(x) ) when g(x) is defined.

How can I fix it? I mean, I don't want to put my function two times...
Anyone can help me?

Comment: Just move the `y = input("Function:")` line right before the `def f(x):` line?

Comment: Great!!!! Thank you!